# MySQL syntax error in "DELETE FROM"

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, sql-delete

Well, I'm making a PHP script that find any row WHERE user_id is equal to the user_id of the user logged and if find any row with the same user_id as the user, "moves" all rows from **friend_requests** with her user_id to a new table called **friend_requestes_notificated**

Is everything OK in my script, except the code that Delete the row after copy the row to the new table.

---

**That's the error:**

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id=1' at line 1"

---

**CODE:**

```
<?php include_once("includes/head.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/connect/connect.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/jquery.php"); ?>

<?php function friend_request_notification(){

global $db;
global $userid;

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$query_id_see = "SELECT user_id FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id=\"{$userid}\" ";
$result_set3 = mysql_query($query_id_see, $db)  or die(mysql_error());

$change_table = "INSERT INTO friend_requests_notificated (id, user_id, user_id_requester) SELECT id, user_id, user_id_requester FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id={$userid} DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id={$userid}";

$change_table2 = mysql_query($change_table) or die(mysql_error());

if ($id_requests = mysql_fetch_array($result_set3)){
}

else

{
}

}

if ($id_requests = mysql_fetch_array($change_table2)){
}

else
{
}


friend_request_notification();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your insert query and delete query. You can't do both at once. (And I see a select query in there. That needs to be its own query, too).

```
$insert_table = "INSERT INTO friend_requests_notificated (id, user_id, user_id_requester) SELECT id, user_id, user_id_requester FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id={$userid}";
$change_table2 = mysql_query($insert_table) or die(mysql_error());

$delete_table = "DELETE FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id={$userid}";
$change_table3 = mysql_query($delete_table) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, [please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks :D
And yes, I know that my mysql API will be removed, but I have so much lines of code that I'm to lazy to change everything